# Addition Multiplication on Different ID using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am designing shopping cart website. and Fresher in Jquery My layout is

[image]

I want to increment and Decrements value by one when Plus and Minus Button is pressed. also the total value for price should also be changed. I tried following jquery code.

```
//Add and Subtract
$("#add").on('click',function()
{
        if(parseInt($("#total input").val())>=0)
        $("#total input").val(parseInt($("#total input").val())+1);
});
$("#sub").on('click',function()
{
        if(parseInt($("input").val())>0)
        $("#total input").val(parseInt($("#total input").val())-1);
});
```

My html Code is:

```html
<div class="btn_group" id="total">
<a href="#" class="btn_add_subtract" id="add">
 +
</a>
<input type="text" class="quantity_value" value="0"/>
<a href="#" class="btn_add_subtract" id="sub">
 -
</a>
</div>
```

But my problem is. 
When i Increment and Decrements the value all the list data is changed. can anyone tell me the better way so I can do that.

Thanks

Comment: Post the HTML or better create a fiddle ..

Comment: You need to show the html code. I think what happening you are not having different ID's for each of the totals and input buttons. For this to work every single item on the page need to have different ID's - if not you will have the problem you are describing.

Comment: if I add different id I have to write different jquery.! right?

Comment: You can use class instead of id, I think you have repeated block of similar html

Comment: Share your html... since ID has to be unique... you can use class to group similar functionality

Comment: The basic skeleton can be something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yknsgrr0/1/ - If you can edit the fiddle to have your html sample

Comment: @arun ok your link is helpful i think m trying as per your suggestion.!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic skeleton to the problem can be as follows, the only need change will be how the `input` element will be found in relation to the clicked button.

Since we have multiple buttons to which same functionality have to be attached, we should use same class to those elements(add/minus buttons) so that we can easily target them.

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  $(this).prev().val(function(i, val) {
    return (+val || 0) + 1;
  });
});
$('.minus').click(function() {
  $(this).next().val(function(i, val) {
    val = (+val || 0) - 1;
    return val < 0 ? 0 : val;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="minus">-</span><input name="x"/><span class="add">+</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="minus">-</span><input name="x"/><span class="add">+</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="minus">-</span><input name="x"/><span class="add">+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use classes instead of ids.

Use a container element to group the elements for an item:

```
<!-- This repeats for each item -->
<div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="total">$</div>
    <button type="button" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="text" class="quantity" value="0"/>
    <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
</div>
```

Use `this` inside the click-event handlers to reference the button that was clicked, and then use `.closest()` to go up to the container element and `.find()` to search back down for the other elements.

```
$(".add").on('click',function()
{
    var $itemContainer = $(this).closest('.itemContainer'),
        $quantity = $itemContainer.find('.quantity'),
        $total = $itemContainer.find('.total');

    // Here you can work with the quantity input and total div for just this item.         
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `class` instead of `id` -

```
$(".add").on('click',function()
{
        var input = $(this).closest(".total input");
        if(parseInt(input.val())>=0)
        input.val(parseInt(input.val())+1);
});
$(".sub").on('click',function()
{
        var input = $(this).closest(".total input");
        if(parseInt(input.val())>=0)
        input.val(parseInt(input.val())-1);
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your buttons and the textbox wrapped in a common div;

```
$("#add").on('click',function()
{
        if(parseInt($("#total input").val())>=0)
        $(this).parent().find("#total input").val(parseInt($(this).parent().find("#total input").val())+1);
});
$("#sub").on('click',function()
{
        if(parseInt($("input").val())>0)
        $(this).parent().find("#total input").val(parseInt($(this).parent().find("#total input").val())-1);
});
```

I'd suggest keeping a common variable for repetitive selections.